# Require a trait to implement a Distribution<T> for the Standard Distribution

Tags: rust, traits, type-parameter

I am trying to build a trait that requires implementors to implment the Distribution for the Standard distribution of the `rand` crate.

I have recently learn how to make this a trait implementor to also implement the display trait with [SuperTraits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait) and I would like to do a similar thing for the trait bound `Standard: Distribution<Self>`. I can add this trait bound with a where clause as such:

```
use rand::{Rng, distributions::{Distribution, Standard}}; // rand 0.7
use std::fmt;

trait SampleAndDisplay: fmt::Display + Sized
where
    Standard: Distribution<Self>
{
    fn other_requirement() -> u16;
}

// For any type to implement SampleAndDisplay, they need the following at least:
struct Implementor;

impl SampleAndDisplay for Implementor {
    fn other_requirement() -> u16 {
        // ...
    }
}

impl fmt::Display for Implementor {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        // ...
    }
}

impl Distribution<Implementor> for Standard {
    fn sample<R: Rng + ?Sized>(&self, rng: &mut R) -> Implementor {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But the problem I have with this is I now need to add an additional trait bound whenever I use `SampleAndDisplay`:

```
fn func<T>()
where
    T: SampleAndDisplay,
    Standard: Distribution<T>, // Would like to not have to always put this
{
    // ...
}
```

In a sense, I think I would like to do the following, but I can't figure out the right syntax, or this is even possible:

```
trait SampleAndDisplay: (Standard: Distribution<Self>) + fmt::Display + Sized
{
    fn other_requirement() -> u16;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This looks related to [issue #20671](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671).